# Binary XML file: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have a very frustrating error that I cannot explain. I created an Android application that uses Android AppCompat to make it compatible with older versions. Here is my main activity layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.music.urgames.geo.MainActivity">

 <!-- Line with Latitude and Longitude -->
 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
 android:paddingTop="5dp"
 android:paddingLeft="15dp"
 android:paddingRight="15dp"
 android:paddingBottom="5dp">

 <!--Latitude-->
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/lat"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 android:layout_weight="0.5"
 android:text="Lat: " />

 <!--Longitude-->
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/lon"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 android:layout_weight="0.5"
 android:text="Long: " />
 </LinearLayout>


 <!--GoogleMap fragment-->
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Main Class

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
        ResultCallback<Status> {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private GoogleMap map;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private Location lastLocation;

    private TextView textLat, textLong;

    private MapFragment mapFragment;

    private static final String NOTIFICATION_MSG = "NOTIFICATION MSG";
    // Create a Intent send by the notification
    public static Intent makeNotificationIntent(Context context, String msg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( context, MainActivity.class );
        intent.putExtra( NOTIFICATION_MSG, msg );
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
        textLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);

        // initialize GoogleMaps
        initGMaps();

        // create GoogleApiClient
        createGoogleApi();
    }

    // Create GoogleApiClient instance
    private void createGoogleApi() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGoogleApi()");
        if ( googleApiClient == null ) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
                    .addConnectionCallbacks( this )
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener( this )
                    .addApi( LocationServices.API )
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Call GoogleApiClient connection when starting the Activity
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // Disconnect GoogleApiClient when stopping Activity
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

  /*  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate( R.menu.main_menu, menu );
        return true;
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch ( item.getItemId() ) {
            case R.id.geofence: {
                startGeofence();
                return true;
            }
            case R.id.clear: {
                clearGeofence();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private final int REQ_PERMISSION = 999;

    // Check for permission to access Location
    private boolean checkPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkPermission()");
        // Ask for permission if it wasn't granted yet
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED );
    }

    // Asks for permission
    private void askPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, "askPermission()");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                REQ_PERMISSION
        );
    }

    // Verify user's response of the permission requested
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult()");
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch ( requestCode ) {
            case REQ_PERMISSION: {
                if ( grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
                    // Permission granted
                    getLastKnownLocation();

                } else {
                    // Permission denied
                    permissionsDenied();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // App cannot work without the permissions
    private void permissionsDenied() {
        Log.w(TAG, "permissionsDenied()");
        // TODO close app and warn user
    }

    // Initialize GoogleMaps
    private void initGMaps(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        }
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    // Callback called when Map is ready
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady()");
        map = googleMap;
        map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapClick("+latLng +")");
        markerForGeofence(latLng);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMarkerClickListener: " + marker.getPosition() );
        return false;
    }

    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    // Defined in mili seconds.
    // This number in extremely low, and should be used only for debug
    private final int UPDATE_INTERVAL =  1000;
    private final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 900;

    // Start location Updates
    private void startLocationUpdates(){
        Log.i(TAG, "startLocationUpdates()");
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        if ( checkPermission() )
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged ["+location+"]");
        lastLocation = location;
        writeActualLocation(location);
    }

    // GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks connected
    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected()");
        getLastKnownLocation();
        recoverGeofenceMarker();
    }

    // GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks suspended
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended()");
    }

    // GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener fail
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionFailed()");
    }

    // Get last known location
    private void getLastKnownLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation()");
        if ( checkPermission() ) {
            lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            if ( lastLocation != null ) {
                Log.i(TAG, "LasKnown location. " +
                        "Long: " + lastLocation.getLongitude() +
                        " | Lat: " + lastLocation.getLatitude());
                writeLastLocation();
                startLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "No location retrieved yet");
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
        }
        else askPermission();
    }

    private void writeActualLocation(Location location) {
        textLat.setText( "Lat: " + location.getLatitude() );
        textLong.setText( "Long: " + location.getLongitude() );

        markerLocation(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    }

    private void writeLastLocation() {
        writeActualLocation(lastLocation);
    }

    private Marker locationMarker;
    private void markerLocation(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.i(TAG, "markerLocation("+latLng+")");
        String title = latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title(title);
        if ( map!=null ) {
            if ( locationMarker != null )
                locationMarker.remove();
            locationMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
            float zoom = 14f;
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    }


    private Marker geoFenceMarker;
    private void markerForGeofence(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.i(TAG, "markerForGeofence("+latLng+")");
        String title = latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude;
        // Define marker options
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))
                .title(title);
        if ( map!=null ) {
            // Remove last geoFenceMarker
            if (geoFenceMarker != null)
                geoFenceMarker.remove();

            geoFenceMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);

        }
    }

    // Start Geofence creation process
    private void startGeofence() {
        Log.i(TAG, "startGeofence()");
        if( geoFenceMarker != null ) {
            Geofence geofence = createGeofence( geoFenceMarker.getPosition(), GEOFENCE_RADIUS );
            GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest( geofence );
            addGeofence( geofenceRequest );
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Geofence marker is null");
        }
    }

    private static final long GEO_DURATION = 60 * 60 * 1000;
    private static final String GEOFENCE_REQ_ID = "My Geofence";
    private static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 500.0f; // in meters

    // Create a Geofence
    private Geofence createGeofence( LatLng latLng, float radius ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofence");
        return new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_REQ_ID)
                .setCircularRegion( latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, radius)
                .setExpirationDuration( GEO_DURATION )
                .setTransitionTypes( Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                        | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
                .build();
    }

    // Create a Geofence Request
    private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest( Geofence geofence ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofenceRequest");
        return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .setInitialTrigger( GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER )
                .addGeofence( geofence )
                .build();
    }

    private PendingIntent geoFencePendingIntent;
    private final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;
    private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Log.d(TAG, "createGeofencePendingIntent");
        if ( geoFencePendingIntent != null )
            return geoFencePendingIntent;

        Intent intent = new Intent( this, GeofenceTrasitionService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(
                this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
    }

    // Add the created GeofenceRequest to the device's monitoring list
    private void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
        Log.d(TAG, "addGeofence");
        if (checkPermission())
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    googleApiClient,
                    request,
                    createGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResult: " + status);
        if ( status.isSuccess() ) {
            saveGeofence();
            drawGeofence();
        } else {
            // inform about fail
        }
    }

    // Draw Geofence circle on GoogleMap
    private Circle geoFenceLimits;
    private void drawGeofence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "drawGeofence()");

        if ( geoFenceLimits != null )
            geoFenceLimits.remove();

        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
                .center( geoFenceMarker.getPosition())
                .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70,70,70))
                .fillColor( Color.argb(100, 150,150,150) )
                .radius( GEOFENCE_RADIUS );
        geoFenceLimits = map.addCircle( circleOptions );
    }

    private final String KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT = "GEOFENCE LATITUDE";
    private final String KEY_GEOFENCE_LON = "GEOFENCE LONGITUDE";

    // Saving GeoFence marker with prefs mng
    private void saveGeofence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "saveGeofence()");
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        editor.putLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT, Double.doubleToRawLongBits( geoFenceMarker.getPosition().latitude ));
        editor.putLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON, Double.doubleToRawLongBits( geoFenceMarker.getPosition().longitude ));
        editor.apply();
    }

    // Recovering last Geofence marker
    private void recoverGeofenceMarker() {
        Log.d(TAG, "recoverGeofenceMarker");
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE );

        if ( sharedPref.contains( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT ) && sharedPref.contains( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON )) {
            double lat = Double.longBitsToDouble( sharedPref.getLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT, -1 ));
            double lon = Double.longBitsToDouble( sharedPref.getLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON, -1 ));
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng( lat, lon );
            markerForGeofence(latLng);
            drawGeofence();
        }
    }

    // Clear Geofence
    private void clearGeofence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "clearGeofence()");
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(
                googleApiClient,
                createGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                if ( status.isSuccess() ) {
                    // remove drawing
                    removeGeofenceDraw();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void removeGeofenceDraw() {
        Log.d(TAG, "removeGeofenceDraw()");
        if ( geoFenceMarker != null)
            geoFenceMarker.remove();
        if ( geoFenceLimits != null )
            geoFenceLimits.remove();
    }

}

  <!--GoogleMap fragment-->
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The error I am getting is

```
03-13 18:00:04.105 16410-16410/com.music.urgames.geo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.music.urgames.geo, PID: 16410
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.music.urgames.geo/com.music.urgames.geo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
```

The geo Translation class

```
public class GeofenceTrasitionService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = GeofenceTrasitionService.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final int GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

    public GeofenceTrasitionService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        // Handling errors
        if ( geofencingEvent.hasError() ) {
            String errorMsg = getErrorString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode() );
            Log.e( TAG, errorMsg );
            return;
        }

        int geoFenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
        // Check if the transition type is of interest
        if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT ) {
            // Get the geofence that were triggered
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(geoFenceTransition, triggeringGeofences );

            // Send notification details as a String
            sendNotification( geofenceTransitionDetails );
        }
    }


    private String getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(int geoFenceTransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
        // get the ID of each geofence triggered
        ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences ) {
            triggeringGeofencesList.add( geofence.getRequestId() );
        }

        String status = null;
        if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER )
            status = "Entering ";
        else if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
            status = "Exiting ";
        return status + TextUtils.join( ", ", triggeringGeofencesList);
    }

    private void sendNotification( String msg ) {
        Log.i(TAG, "sendNotification: " + msg );

        // Intent to start the main Activity
        Intent notificationIntent = MainActivity.makeNotificationIntent(
                getApplicationContext(), msg
        );

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
        }
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }


        // Creating and sending Notification
        NotificationManager notificatioMng =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        notificatioMng.notify(
                GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                createNotification(msg, notificationPendingIntent));

    }

    // Create notification
    private Notification createNotification(String msg, PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent) {
        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location)
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(msg)
                .setContentText("Geofence Notification!")
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        return notificationBuilder.build();
    }


    private static String getErrorString(int errorCode) {
        switch (errorCode) {
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                return "GeoFence not available";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
                return "Too many GeoFences";
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
                return "Too many pending intents";
            default:
                return "Unknown error.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_Binary XML file line #44:_" Which line is #44?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two LinearLayouts but you are only closing one

Comment: both are closed